# авторизация android клиента на appengine

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-services

такая ситуация, есть android клиент, есть endpoint у которого указан User

вроде все CLIENT_ID  и AUDIENCE_ID указаны

RequestInitializer пытается получить, но даже если я вызывал setSelectedAccountName валится исключение

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: the name must not be empty: null
```

Answer (score 1):

Все оказалось достаточно просто, в 23 API появились же runtime permitions так вот надо же дать сначала приложению права на GET_ACCOUNTS